# How I can remove reference from a wiki article using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the article that I have:

> Beginning in the 1st century BC with Virgil, Horace, and Strabo, Roman
>   histories offer only vague accounts of China and the silk-producing
>   Seres people of the Far East, who were perhaps the ancient
>   Chinese.[2][3] The 2nd-century AD Roman historian Florus seems to have
>   confused the Seres with peoples of India, or at least noted that their
>   skin complexions proved that they both lived "beneath another sky"
>   than the Romans.[2] Roman authors generally seem to have demonstrated
>   some confusion as to where the Seres were located precisely, in either
>   Central Asia or East Asia.[4] The 1st-century AD geographer Pomponius
>   Mela asserted that the lands of the Seres formed the center of the
>   coast of an eastern ocean, flanked to the south by India and to the
>   north by the Scythians of the Eurasian Steppe.[2] The historian
>   Ammianus Marcellinus (c. 330 – c. 400 AD) wrote that the land of the
>   Seres was enclosed by great natural walls around a river called
>   Bautis, possibly a description of the Yellow River.[2]

This article is available in a file to me.  I have tried to extract the text in a list using the file open method.

```
with open('test.txt','r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as tit:
    for i in tit:
        lines.append(i.strip()) # extracting the text line by line without newline characters.
```

But now in the result what I am getting is the wiki article with lines and the reference numbers. I do not understand how I can remove the reference numbers as they are trouble in my further process.

Kindly, suggest me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`. like this.

```
import re

lines = []
with open('test.txt','r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as tit:
    for i in tit:
        lines.append(re.sub('\[\d+\]', '', i.strip()))
```

Comment: It is leaving a space in the middle where it is the pattern found .. how to trim this....?

Comment: @JafferWilson what have you tried to get rid of the space?

Comment: I have tried to using the `strip()` to remove spaces but not working

Comment: @JafferWilson Do you want to remove both reference numbers and spaces?   like this?   `the Romans.[2] Roman authors`  => `theRomans.Romanauthors`

Comment: @JafferWilson read about [strip](https://www.dotnetperls.com/strip-python) then think of another solution, maybe with regex?

Comment: Thank you.. its done... :) Hence, I accepted your answer.